# How to replace Delete word with Font Awesome in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, font-awesome

I am trying to replace **Delete** word with Font Awesome icon in jQuery. I have googling and searching but not find any solution.

**JS**

```
columns: [
    { "data" : "filename", 
           render: function ( data ) {
           return "<span onclick='download_file(&quot;"+data+"&quot;)'>Download</span> / <span onclick='delete_file(&quot;"+data+"&quot;)'>Delete</span>";     
    } }
],
```

**Font Awesome**

```
<i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly have your icon code in your render return string like below

```
render: function ( data ) {
       return "<span onclick='download_file(&quot;"+data+"&quot;)'>Download</span> / <span onclick='delete_file(&quot;"+data+"&quot;)'><i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i></span>";     
}
```

But only thing when you rendering this element in DOM then you should use `html` method of jquery like below

```
$('Your Selector').html(render_function_call);
```

Comment: Actually I have tried this before and after this posting, I realize that I need to use single code (' ') instead of using double code (" "). thanks anyway.